# DateFormatter from "24:00" string returns Nil

Tags: ios, swift, date

I cannot seem to figure out why only "24:00" returns nil instead of 12:00AM, whereas "23:59" returns correctly as 11:59PM.

```
let dateAsString = "24:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
let Date12 = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
print(Date12)
```

Comment: 24 is invalid. Hours are in the range 0-23.

Comment: thanks, makes sense, but I have an embedded controller I'm interfacing with that returns 24 for 12pm... I'll work around it.

Comment: If anything, 24:00 should be treated as 12am, not 12pm. 12am is midnight. 12pm is noon. 00:00 and 24:00 could be considered the same and both would be 12am.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong date format for the hour component. For values from 1-24 you have to use `k`, if you have a leading zero you need to use `kk`:

```
let dateAsString = "24:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "kk:mm"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateAsString) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    let date2 = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(date2) // "12:00 AM\n"
}
```